# Stronger bound for a prime that satisfies Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: number-theory

The prime number theorem itself also proves a stronger asymptotic version of Bertrand's postulate, namely that for every $ε>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ there exists a prime between $n$ and $(1+ε)n$ .

However, for any **Even** $n\geq2750$ (which I found experimentally), my claim is that, there exists a prime $p$ s.t.
$$\frac{n}{\pi} \le p\le \frac{n}{e}$$
and the unique property of $p$ is such that $n-p$ is prime as well.

Hence if $p$ and $n-p$ both are prime, we get 2 primes which satisfy Goldbach's conjecture. I have verified this for all even numbers till 50 Million and will do the same for larger numbers.

Meanwhile, is there any formal proof for such an intuition? Does this seem to introduce a stronger bound?

Comment: I am not sure how you have determined that these $p$ imply $n-p$ is prime (because that would in fact prove Goldbach's conjecture!), but your bound seems to be a natural consequence if you choose $\epsilon=\pi/e-1$ in your PNT expression.

Comment: I have found this by simulating this on a computer but don't have a rigorous proof for the same. I have always been able to find some prime p in the bounds mentioned above, s.t. n-p is prime as well. There could be multiple primes in the given range, but there exists at least one which seems to make this true.

Comment: The same heuristics that lead to Goldbach's conjecture also lead to conjectures about the distribution of the number of solutions to $p+q=n$ in primes $p,q$. In particular, those conjectures imply that for any real numbers $0<\alpha<\beta<1$, once $n$ is (even and) large enough in terms of $\alpha,\beta$, there will exist a prime $p\in(\alpha n,\beta n)$ such that $n-p$ is also prime. So there's nothing special about $\alpha=\frac1\pi$ and $\beta=\frac1e$ here.

Comment: This claim is stronger than the Goldbach conjecture , so assuming that there is a formal proof is extremely optimistic indeed. The range is however probably still large enough to guarantee a Goldbach partition. The best you can do is probably to extend the search range, but $50$ million is already quite convincing.